# Stuck at starting 'node server.js' .. won't get any output. What's the issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So this is what I have in my server.js file.

```
 var app = require('express')();
 bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.listen(3000);

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended true
 }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.get('/items', function(req, res) {

     data = {
         brains: "squishy",
         relationships: "squishy",
         tickles: "harsh",
         taste: "sweet"
     }

     console.log(data.brains);
 });
```

I want all of my data as an output so I console logged data.brains and then when i checked my node inside my terminal, it will not generate any output getting stuck at starting 'node server.js' .. I don't know why it's not working. What is the issue?

Comment: what did you do, exactly? From what I understand, what you should be doing is: 1) run `node server.js` 2) while the command is still running, go to `http://localhost:3000/` in a browser 3) check the console again

Comment: You should be going to `http://localhost:3000/items` after fixing the error that Jordan pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to run an HTTP request to your server to trigger that logging.  Try visiting http://localhost:3000/items and it should log "squishy" as expected.

Essentially this code in your example registers the callback within it to respond to such an HTTP request:

```
app.get('/items', function(req, res) {

     data = {
         brains: "squishy",
         relationships: "squishy",
         tickles: "harsh",
         taste: "sweet"
     }

     console.log(data.brains);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you have a syntax error on line 6. `{extended true}` isn't valid JavaScript.